# Custom navigation bar for pushed UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

How do I set a title and buttons on the navigation bar of a pushed view controller if I push it onto navigationController with `navigationController.pushViewController(controller:animated:completion:)`, whilst keeping the "**Back**" button?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can set the title and bar items in the `viewDidLoad` method of pushed view controller

Comment: @pkc456 Oh, that's right, I tried to access `navigationItem` through `self.navigationController?.navigationItem`, rather than directly.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering how to do this, just override your pushed `UIViewController`'s `navigationItem` property directly. My mistake was that I was trying to accomplish this with `self.navigationController?.navigationItem`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code, that you should write in order to set the navigation title as well as left button

**Code :**

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    //For Setting Title
    self.title = "New Title";

    //For setting button in place of back button
    let leftItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Cancel, target: self, action: "leftButtonClicked");
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftItem;
}
```

Happy coding ...